How do I modularize functions that work with dask?
I'm trying to modularize my functions that use Dask, but I keep encountering the error "No module named 'setup'". I can't import any local module that is related to Dask, and currently, everything I do with Dask has to be in a single .py file. How do I properly modularize functions that use Dask?
Here's an example of my setup:

main.py: Contains functions that utilize Dask.
setup.py: A local module I created, which also contains functions using Dask.

I'm attempting to import the setup module in main.py like this:
from setup import *

class CustomModulePlugin(WorkerPlugin):
    def setup(self, worker):
        import setup

    def start(self, worker):
        logging.warning("Plugin started and added to the worker.")

client = Client('tcp://127.0.0.1:8786')
client.register_worker_plugin(CustomModulePlugin())

But I keep getting the following error:
No module named 'setup'

try renaming it to sth like dask_setup.py and see if it works. it should be then from dask_setup import *

The workers see a different filesystem than your client. When tasks are sent, only as much is serialised as required, to keep the communication as small as possible - so functions and classes in modules are NOT packed, only a reference for which module to find the definition in.
Therefore, the workers need to have access to the same modules as your client.
There are many ways to ensure this kind of environment synching. Perhaps the simplest one for you is upload_file, which will send the code to all workers and ensure it is in an importable location.
Other options include:

shared filesystems, e.g., NFS or kube shared volume
nanny-mediated file upload (see here]
publishing the code in any python format (.egg, .zip etc), and use the environ plugin to install it in new workers.
"coiled" cluster, which includes source file syncing (doc)
since you are using a plugin already, you can have its setup method write the file first, and defer import until after setup (inside tasks, rather than in main)


I have tested the solution with upload_file and it did not work in my case.
I work with a system of backup workers that are automatically created when the current VMs go down. Because of this, I cannot use upload_file, as I need something that works for both the workers that have already been created and those that will be created in the future.
Do you have any suggestions on how to dynamically synchronize the environment to cover future workers as well?

I included some idea sketches. Let us know what you end up using!

We tested all the suggestions, except the coiled cluster, as it would change the project architecture a lot. Neither solution worked, however. We use the compute API from GCP to manage the machines

Publishing your package certainly works!
